# How to draw an arrow using android graphic class?

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas, draw

How can i draw an arrow using the graphics class?

Im using android graphics class and basically im trying to show a path on a map. So i need to print an arrow head on the canvas. Help me to figure out!

Thank you!

This is one of the methods i have used to draw a line. i want to print an arrow head on the edge of each and every line.

```
//       ArrayList<Point> ArrayListPoints = new ArrayList<Point>(); // Assign the shortest path here

//       ArrayListPoints.add(new Point(262,100));
//       ArrayListPoints.add(new Point(262,165));
//       ArrayListPoints.add(new Point(346,165));
//       ArrayListPoints.add(new Point(420,165));

       ArrayList<Point> ArrayListPointsFINAL;

    ArrayListPointsFINAL = storePath.ArrayListPoints;

    if(ArrayListPointsFINAL == null){
        System.out.println("ArrayListPointsFINAL is NULL");
    }
    else{

    ArrayList<Float> ArrayList_X = new ArrayList<Float>();
     ArrayList<Float> ArrayList_Y = new ArrayList<Float>();
     //int size = get.ArrayListPoints.size();

    for(int i=0; i<ArrayListPointsFINAL.size(); i++){
        ArrayList_X.add(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(ArrayListPointsFINAL.get(i).x)));
        ArrayList_Y.add(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(ArrayListPointsFINAL.get(i).y)));
          }   

    for(int i=1; i<ArrayList_X.size(); i++){
        Paint myPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(8/*1 /getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density*/);
        myPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);   //color.RED
       // myPaint.setStyle(myPaint);

       canvas.drawLine(ArrayList_X.get(i), ArrayList_Y.get(i), ArrayList_X.get(i-1), ArrayList_Y.get(i-1),myPaint);       

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it yet? Please, post some failed attempts if you need help.

Comment: done :) give me tips on how to draw an arrow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw a Bitmap instead and apply a matrix to it.

Answer (score 9):

Hope you'll still find this useful; here's how I draw an arrow head:

```
    private void fillArrow(Canvas canvas, float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1) {

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    float deltaX = x1 - x0;
    float deltaY = y1 - y0;
    float frac = (float) 0.1;

    float point_x_1 = x0 + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaX + frac * deltaY);
    float point_y_1 = y0 + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaY - frac * deltaX);

    float point_x_2 = x1;
    float point_y_2 = y1;

    float point_x_3 = x0 + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaX - frac * deltaY);
    float point_y_3 = y0 + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaY + frac * deltaX);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

    path.moveTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
    path.lineTo(point_x_2, point_y_2);
    path.lineTo(point_x_3, point_y_3);
    path.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
    path.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

Given a line with end points at p(x0, y0) and p(x1, y1), the method draws an arrow head with its vertex at p(x1, y1).

The variable

```
frac : 0 < frac < 1
```

determines the size of the arrow head.

Answer (score 3):

When I used Igwe Kalu's solution, the size of the arrow head varied according to the distance between the points.

Here is my solution for making the arrow head a constant size, independent of the distance between the points.

```
private void fillArrow(Canvas canvas, float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1) {
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    float deltaX = x1 - x0;
    float deltaY = y1 - y0;
    double distance = Math.sqrt((deltaX * deltaX) + (deltaY * deltaY));
    float frac = (float) (1 / (distance / 30));

    float point_x_1 = x0 + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaX + frac * deltaY);
    float point_y_1 = y0 + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaY - frac * deltaX);

    float point_x_2 = x1;
    float point_y_2 = y1;

    float point_x_3 = x0 + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaX - frac * deltaY);
    float point_y_3 = y0 + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaY + frac * deltaX);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

    path.moveTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
    path.lineTo(point_x_2, point_y_2);
    path.lineTo(point_x_3, point_y_3);
    path.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
    path.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same is worked ... But for illustration.. call the below method in onDraw.. so that you could see how it working...

```
private void fillArrow(Canvas canvas, float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    float deltaX = x1 - x0;
    float deltaY = y1 - y0;
    float distance = (float) Math.sqrt((deltaX * deltaX)
            + (deltaY * deltaY));
    float frac = (float) (1 / (distance / 15));

    float point_x_1 = x0 + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaX + frac * deltaY);
    float point_y_1 = y0 + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaY - frac * deltaX);

    float point_x_2 = x1;
    float point_y_2 = y1;

    float point_x_3 = x0 + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaX - frac * deltaY);
    float point_y_3 = y0 + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaY + frac * deltaX);

    float midOfArrow_x = (point_x_1 + point_x_3) / 2;
    float midOfArrow_y = (point_y_1 + point_y_3) / 2;

    Path path = new Path();
    path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

    path.moveTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
    path.lineTo(point_x_2, point_y_2);
    path.lineTo(point_x_3, point_y_3);
    path.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
    // path.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
    path.close();

    path.transform(mMatrix);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(9);
    path = new Path();

    path.moveTo(x0, y0);
    path.lineTo(midOfArrow_x, midOfArrow_y);
    path.transform(mMatrix);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    canvas.drawCircle(x0, y0, 10, paint);

    canvas.drawCircle(midOfArrow_x, midOfArrow_y, 10, paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawCircle(point_x_1, point_y_1, 10, paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawCircle(point_x_2, point_y_2, 10, paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawCircle(point_x_3, point_y_3, 10, paint);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

// using a custom View, you can draw using path primitives:

```
  private Paint mPaint;                 // paint object
  private Path mPathGrid;                   // path object

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {

        if (mPaint == null)
         mPaint = new Paint();                   // cache your paint object
            if (mPathGrid == null)
     mPathGrid = new Path();                 // and your path

        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        // a white arrow pointing down
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        mPathGrid.reset();
        mPathGrid.moveTo(100.0, 100.0);         // 100,100 is starting point of path

                // "draw" the outline of your arrow... play "connect the dots"...
        mPathGrid.lineTo(100.0 + 10.0f, 100.0);
        mPathGrid.lineTo(100.0 + 10.0f, 100.0 - 5.0f);
        mPathGrid.lineTo(100.0 + 13.0f, 100.0 - 5.0f);
        mPathGrid.lineTo(100.0 + 10.0f, 100.0 - 8.0f);
        mPathGrid.lineTo(100.0 + 7.0f, 100.0 - 5.0f);
        mPathGrid.lineTo(100.0 + 10.0f, 100.0 - 5.0f);
        canvas.drawPath(mPathGrid, mPaint);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

I saw this in your code:

```
for(int i=1; i<ArrayList_X.size(); i++)
{ 
        Paint myPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG); 
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(8/*1 /getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density*/); 
        myPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);   //color.RED 
       // myPaint.setStyle(myPaint); 

       canvas.drawLine(ArrayList_X.get(i), ArrayList_Y.get(i), ArrayList_X.get(i-1), ArrayList_Y.get(i-1),myPaint);        

    }
```

don't create new Paint objects within a loop like this, you only need one!  And you only need to set properties like stroke width, color, etc, once.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create an `arrow bitmap` and with the following code from my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192757/android-rotate-bitmap-around-center-without-resizing), you can turn the arrow with ease.

I hope this helps.

Comment: could you tell me how to draw a bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

I try this code it has been working perfectly

```
Here is my code...

switch (event.getAction())
{
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        startPoint = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
        endPoint = new PointF();
        invalidate();

     //   isDrawing = true;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        System.out.println("action move");
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE)
        {
        //  currentDrawingPath.path.quadTo(mX,mY,(x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
        }
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
          endPoint.x = event.getX();
            endPoint.y = event.getY();
          isDrawing = true;

          invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
           float deltaX =   endPoint.x-startPoint.x;
           float deltaY =   endPoint.y-startPoint.y;
           float frac = (float) 0.1;

       float point_x_1 = startPoint.x + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaX + frac * deltaY);
       float point_y_1 = startPoint.y + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaY - frac * deltaX);

           float point_x_2 = endPoint.x;
           float point_y_2 = endPoint.y;

       float point_x_3 = startPoint.x + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaX - frac * deltaY);
       float point_y_3 = startPoint.y + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaY + frac * deltaX);



           mPath.moveTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
           mPath.lineTo(point_x_2, point_y_2);
           mPath.lineTo(point_x_3, point_y_3);
           mPath.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
           mPath.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, ppaint);
            endPoint.x = event.getX();
            endPoint.y = event.getY();
            isDrawing = false;
            invalidate();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```