# Draw line with bitmap which change StopX and StopY

Tags: java, android, matrix

I am developing a compass application in which I want to make a compass with a good user interface, specifically where compass needle show as good bitmap. I have implemented functionality very well and it is working fine but there is a problem with the needle. I Want to set a bitmap as a line and rotate it independently. There is an `n` parameter for bitmap object to change stopX and StopY parameter as given in a **Line** object.

Can you suggest a solution or alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you would like to rotate the Bitmap according to the compass direction? If this is the case, you should have a look at my Thread which helped me solve this problem: [Android rotate bitmap around center without resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192757/android-rotate-bitmap-around-center-without-resizing)

I hope this helps.