# Rotating ImageView in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation

Please take a look at this picture:

[image: Before]

I want to rotate this ImageView, but when I do so, only the visible part of the circle is rotated, and the rest is cropped, like in the following picture:

[image: After]

What is the best solution to my problem? I've managed to partialy solve this by rotating source bitmap, cropping it to fit a desired size, and assigning to the ImageView again, but it's just a half measure, although this metod works, it's choppy and doing it this way feels plain wrong, because it requires to create a new bitmap every time an image is rotated. In this particular case, I think moving a part of ImageView outside the layout would do the trick, but I'm also struggling with achieving this in a correct manner, and I'd love to know the general solution. Thanks for Your help.

Comment: You should rotate bitmap using matrix. Follow this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192757/android-rotate-bitmap-around-center-without-resizing)

Comment: Please see my solution here [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546760/how-to-show-half-of-the-imageview-which-is-rotated-using-matrix-in-android/36587838#36587838)