# How to show half of the ImageView which is rotated using Matrix in Android?

Tags: android, matrix, rotation, imageview

Dear fellow StackOverflower,

Follow this example (*code.tutsplus[dot]com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer--mobile-8868*), I'm able to create a rotating `ImageView` using `Matrix`. The logic is as the following:

- Load the `Bitmap` into the `ImageView`
- Rotate the `ImageView` using a `Matrix` on touch event.

This will guarantee performance as the `Bitmap` doesn't get drawn every time the wheel rotate. However I would like to display only half of the wheel, and the content of the [**image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoxLd.png) is dynamic so it won't be possible to cut the image in half and then rotate following the steps above.

I've investigated in `ClipDrawable`, however from what I understand, it's directly clipping the resource `Bitmap` so in order to make it work, I would have to fall back to the redraw `Bitmap` method (which has terrible performance).

Is there a way to limit the display of the `ImageView` so only a portion of it will be displayed?

What I've done so far:

*MyRotateWheel* class:

```
public class MyRotateWheelView extends ImageView {
private MyMatrixHelper mMatrixHelper;
private int mWheelHeight, mWheelWidth;

public MyRotateWheelView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    loadImage(R.drawable.my_rotate_wheel);
    initWheel();
}

public void loadImage(int id){
    mMatrixHelper = new MyMatrixHelper(getResources(), id);
}

public void initWheel(){
    setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());
    //Since we only know after measuring the layout how much space our ImageView fills, we add an OnGlobalLayoutListener.
    //In the onGlobalLayout method, we can intercept the event that the layout has been drawn and query the size of our view.
    getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // method called more than once, but the values only need to be initialized one time
            if (mMatrixHelper.isNecessaryToScaleImage(getWidth(), getHeight())) {

                mWheelWidth = getWidth();
                mWheelHeight = getHeight();

                setImageBitmap(mMatrixHelper.getImageScaled());
                setImageMatrix(mMatrixHelper.getMatrix());
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Simple implementation of an {@link View.OnTouchListener} for registering the mWheel's touch events.
 */
private class MyOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private double startAngle;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                double currentAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
                double delta = startAngle - currentAngle;

                rotateDialer((float) delta); //rotate

                startAngle = currentAngle;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * @return The angle of the unit circle with the image view's center
 */
private double getAngle(double xTouch, double yTouch) {
    double x = xTouch - (mWheelWidth / 2d);
    double y = mWheelHeight - yTouch - (mWheelHeight / 2d);

    switch (getQuadrant(x, y)) {
        case 1:
            return Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        case 2:
            return 180 - Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        case 3:
            return 180 + (-1 * Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI);
        case 4:
            return 360 + Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

/**
 * @return The selected quadrant.
 */
private static int getQuadrant(double x, double y) {
    if (x >= 0) {
        return y >= 0 ? 1 : 4;
    } else {
        return y >= 0 ? 2 : 3;
    }
}

/**
 * Rotate the mWheel.
 *
 * @param degrees The degrees, the mWheel should get rotated.
 */
private void rotateDialer(int i, float degrees) {
    mMatrixHelper.getMatrix().postRotate(degrees, mWheelWidth / 2, mWheelHeight / 2);
    setImageMatrix(mMatrixHelper.getMatrix());
}
```

}

*MyMatrixHelper* class:

```
public class MyMatrixHelper {
private Bitmap imageOriginal, imageScaled;
private Matrix matrix;
private int mImageHeight, mImageWidth;

public MyMatrixHelper(Resources res, int id){
    // load the image only once
    if (imageOriginal == null) {
        imageOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id);
    }

    // initialize the matrix only once
    if (matrix == null) {
        matrix = new Matrix();
    } else {
        // not needed, you can also post the matrix immediately to restore the old state
        matrix.reset();
    }
}

public boolean isNecessaryToScaleImage(int width, int height){
    if (mImageWidth == 0 || mImageHeight == 0) {
        mImageWidth = width;
        mImageHeight = height;

        // resize
        Matrix resize = new Matrix();
        resize.postScale((float) Math.min(mImageWidth, mImageHeight) / (float) imageOriginal.getWidth(), (float) Math.min(mImageWidth, mImageHeight) / (float) imageOriginal.getHeight());
        imageScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageOriginal, 0, 0, imageOriginal.getWidth(), imageOriginal.getHeight(), resize, false);

        // translate to the image view's center
        float translateX = mImageWidth / 2 - imageScaled.getWidth() / 2;
        float translateY = mImageHeight / 2 - imageScaled.getHeight() / 2;
        matrix.postTranslate(translateX, translateY);

        //imageOriginal.recycle();
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public Bitmap getImageScaled() {
    return imageScaled;
}

public Matrix getMatrix() {
    return matrix;
}
```

In the layout file:

```
<.MyRotateWheelView
...
android:scaleType="matrix"/>
```

**UPADTE 1:**

I've partially solved this problem. I've overridden the `onDraw` method to draw the image into the `ImageView` using an updated `Matrix` on touch event. This guarantee performance as the image  doesn't get redrawn and the image does rotate with proper cropping inside the `ImageView`.

However the remaining problem is the image is currently rotated around the center of the `ImageView`. In order for this solution to work I need to figure out a way to get the coordination of the center of the image itself. Any suggestion?

Code snippet:

```
private class MyOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private double startAngle;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            ...

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                double currentAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
                double delta = startAngle - currentAngle;

                updateMatrix((float)delta);
                invalidate();

                startAngle = currentAngle;
                break;

            ...
        }
        return true;
    }
}

private void updateMatrix(float delta){
    matrix.postRotate(delta, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2); //need to find out the coordination of the center of the image
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, matrix, paint);
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I've figured out how to calculate the coordinate of the image's center. I'm currently making an assumption that the image is bigger than the screen so full solution will be posted when every cases are properly handle.

Unfortunately, I encounter another problem. In order to make my solution works, the bottom of the image must be aligned with the bottom of the `ImageView` and properly centered, like in **Picture A** of this:

[**Picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw1rV.png)

However, the image is drawn into the `ImageView` like in **Picture B**.

I would be very grateful if anyone can show me the way to properly center and align the bottom of the image with the bottom of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear beloved StackOverflower,

I've solved my problem. It's actually very simple. I make the mistake of assuming the rotating `Matrix` follows the screen coordination when in fact it's actually follow the `View` coordination. Please see the picture below:

[**Picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Clw.png)

Then the solution is very simple:

```
getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // method called more than once, but the values only need to be initialized one time
            if (mWheelHeight == 0 || mWheelWidth == 0) {
                mWheelHeight = getHeight();
                mWheelWidth = getWidth();

                // resize
                Matrix resize = new Matrix();
                resize.postScale((float)Math.min(mWheelWidth, mWheelHeight) / (float)imageOriginal.getWidth(), (float)Math.min(mWheelWidth, mWheelHeight) / (float)imageOriginal.getHeight());
                imageScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageOriginal, 0, 0, imageOriginal.getWidth(), imageOriginal.getHeight(), resize, false);
                setImageBitmap(imageScaled);

                // center the image on x axis and move it upward on y axis
                float translateX = mWheelWidth / 2 - imageScaled.getWidth() / 2;                    
                float translateY = -imageScaled.getHeight()/2; //modify this to your liking, I only want to show the bottom half of the image.
                matrix.postTranslate(translateX, translateY);
                setImageMatrix(matrix);
            }
        }
    });
```

The touch event is still the same:

```
private class MyOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private double startAngle;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        ...

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                double currentAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
                double delta = startAngle - currentAngle;

                updateMatrix((float)delta);
                invalidate();

                startAngle = currentAngle;
                break;

         ...
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

An then update the pivot coordinate:

```
private void updateMatrix(float delta){
    matrix.postRotate(delta, getWidth()/2, 0f);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(imageScaled, matrix, paint);
}
```

Thanks you all for your patient.

**Improvement:**

My first solution work fine and all if you just want to display half of the rotating wheel your layout. However, the downside is unused space on your `ImageView` block other `Views` and if you has a complex layout, other `View` below this `ImageView` can't receive touch event. 
With this improved solution, you can limit the size of the `ImageView` so it wont block other `View` as in the Picture below.

[**Picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9V6I.png)

In your *layout.xml*

```
<.MyWheelView
    android:id="@+id/some_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" //change to suit your need
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/protractor_wheel"
    />
```

In the `onGlobalLayout()` method, modify as the following:

```
 @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // method called more than once, but the values only need to be initialized one time
            if (mWheelHeight == 0 || mWheelWidth == 0) {
                mWheelHeight = getHeight();
                mWheelWidth = getWidth();

                // resize
                Matrix resize = new Matrix();
                resize.postScale((float)Math.max(mWheelWidth, mWheelHeight) / (float)imageOriginal.getWidth(), (float)Math.max(mWheelWidth, mWheelHeight) / (float)imageOriginal.getHeight());
                imageScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageOriginal, 0, 0, imageOriginal.getWidth(), imageOriginal.getHeight(), resize, false);
                setImageBitmap(imageScaled);

                // center the image on x axis and move it upward on y axis
                float translateX = mWheelWidth / 2 - imageScaled.getWidth() / 2;
                float translateY = - 0.75f * imageScaled.getHeight(); //edit show how much of the image will get displayed (in my case I move 75% of my image upward)
                matrix.postTranslate(translateX, translateY);
                setImageMatrix(matrix);

                //calculate pivotY only once
                pivotY = 0.25f * imageScaled.getHeight() - (float)imageScaled.getHeight()/2;
            }
        }
    });
```

And then in the `updateMatrix` we do this:

```
private void updateMatrix(float delta){
    matrix.postRotate(delta, getWidth()/2, pivotY);
}
```

I hope my solution could be helpful to you, thanks for your patient.